# Trying to migrate from Vue-cli to Vite and Components are not Rendering

Tags: django, vuejs2, vite, vue-cli

I have this django and vue 2 application that is currently using vue-cli and webpack loader but I'm trying to migrate the application to vite. I've gone through what I thought would be all the steps. But when I build and run the dev server and have it communicate with the backend, loading it at localhost:8000, although I see all the vue, js, sass, scss components in the networks tab in dev tools returning 200s I don't see anything show up on the page. Anyone ever face this issue before and know what the issue might be?

I've followed all the steps from [here](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/how-to-migrate-from-vue-cli-to-vite/) and was expecting my components to at least render even if there were some errors that I could worry about troubleshooting after, but instead I see 200s for all my components in the network tab but a blank page. My django endpoints are also not showing up in the terminal or network tab.